# Firefox: Returning a value from a content script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

When executing a content script, for an active Tab is there a way for that content script to return a value to the popup where the script was executed?

There is a similar question like this for Chromen - but not for FF.

There is a virtual beer for something which helps!

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to send data from the content script back to index.js?

Comment: Ideally. Yes.  That would be the end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#From_Tab.attach()) on MDN about Content Scripts

If you are using the High-Level API Tabs (which I think you are), you need to do the following:

---

### Sending Data to Script

To send a message to the content script, underneath the `var my_tab = tab.attach({ ... })`, add the following:

```js
my_tab.port.emit("my_message", "Message from the add-on")
```

Then inside the script you can use this to listen for the message:

```js
self.port.on("my_message", function(data) {
    // Do stuff here!
    // data contains the data sent (i.e. "Message from the add-on")
})
```

---

### Sending Data to `index.js` from Script

This is the bit you are probably interested in.

To send data from the script, use the following code:

```js
self.port.emit("my_response", "Response from content script")
```

And to receive it in `index.js`:

```js
my_tab.port.on("my_response", function(data) {
    // Do stuff here!
    // data contains the data sent (i.e. "Response from content script")
})
```

Comment: can we return any data from `my_tab.port.on` ?

Comment: @RahulSharma What do you mean "return"?